# Outer join two dataframes based on index without disrupting the original order of both dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I intend to create a table that compares the contents of two dataframes. The indices are part of a process and the order has been predefined. My dataframes look like as below:

df1:

| Index | Content |
| --- | --- |
| xxa | 0 |
| init | 1 |
| tyui | 2 |
| ddas | 3 |
| gsdj | 4 |
| hasf | 5 |

df2:

| Index | Content |
| --- | --- |
| xxa | 1 |
| init | 1 |
| fafa | 6 |
| eafa | 7 |
| gsdj | 6 |
| hasf | 5 |

Intended merged output:

| Index1 | Index2 | Content1 | Content2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| xxa | xxa | 0 | 1 |
| init | init | 1 | 1 |
| tyui |  | 2 |  |
| ddas |  | 3 |  |
|  | fafa |  | 6 |
|  | eafa |  | 7 |
| gsdj | gsdj | 4 | 6 |
| hasf | hasf | 5 | 5 |

I have tried taking the union of the two indices, i.e.

```
index_all = df1.index.union(df2.index, sort=False)
```

However, the indices are sorted as
| Index1| Index2  | Content1 | Content2
| ------| ------- | -------- | --------
| xxa   | xxa     | 0        | 1
| init  | init    | 1        | 1
| tyui  |         |2         |
| ddas  |         |3         |
| gsdj  | gsdj    |4         | 6
| hasf  | hasf    |5         | 5
|       | fafa    |          | 6
|       | eafa    |          | 7

Answer (score 1):

What about something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.concat([df1, df2])["Index"].unique(), columns = ["Index1", "Index2"])

df["Index1"] = df1.set_index("Index", drop = False)
df["Index2"] = df2.set_index("Index", drop = False)

df.sort_index().reset_index(drop = True)
#  Index1 Index2
#0      a      a
#1      b      b
#2      c    NaN
#3      d    NaN
#4    NaN      e
#5    NaN      f
#6      g      g
#7      h      h
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. It's on the right track. However, if my index is e.g. (a,b,f,e,g,h), due to df.sort_index() it will get sorted to a,b, NaN, NaN, e, f, g, h. I would like to maintain the order (f, e).

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Col1': 1, 'Col2': 2}, [*'abcdgh'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Col3': 3, 'Col4': 4}, [*'abefgh'])
```

#### `join`

Using `outer`

```
df1.join(df2, how='outer')

   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4
a   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
b   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
c   1.0   2.0   NaN   NaN
d   1.0   2.0   NaN   NaN
e   NaN   NaN   3.0   4.0
f   NaN   NaN   3.0   4.0
g   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
h   1.0   2.0   3.0   4.0
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your suggestion. Same as the comment from above, my real indices are strings and they will get sorted alphabetically which disrupts their order. Would it be possible to retain their initial order with your method?

Comment: I don't understand how you are determining the order it will be in.  Both sample dataframes have indices in order.  Why don't you provide sample data that demonstrates what you mean.

Comment: I edited my OP. I hope it better illustrates my situation. So, the indices are part of a process flow that is predefined. Just that there are additions/removal/change in order between the two dfs. Unable to provide exact values due to confidentiality issues.

Comment: The problem is, there is no reason to assume that `'fafa'` should come before `'gsdj'`.  `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)` works and doesn't sort.  But it does assume that `df1` indices come first.  You seem to want to interweave the indices somehow and I'm not sure what your expected logic is to determine that order.

Comment: I guess the logic would be traversing through individual indices
1. If both indexes agree --> no action needed
2. If index in df1 not in df2 --> add zero rows in df2 until (1) is fulfilled
3. If index in df2 not in df1 --> add zero rows in df1 until (1) is fulfilled

I tried df.align before but it seems to just add zero rows at the end such that the dims of both dfs are equal.

Comment: but `'fafa'` is in `df2` and not in `df1`.  At what point do we start checking `df2`?  After we've already gone through all of `df1`, right?  If that is true, then we wouldn't have added a row for `'fafa'` until after `'gsdj'`.  My point is, I don't see a way to programmatically get the order you think you should be getting.  I'm not sure if you are married to this ordering or you just know that it shouldn't be sorted after combined.